# Terminating a long-running function in Pyrogram library based on user messages

Tags: python, function, telegram-bot, pyrogram

In the Pyrogram library, I have implemented functions that initiate a long-running process whenever a user sends a "do" message to the bot. Now, I would like to terminate the ongoing function for a specific user whenever they send an "exit" message. Because the user may give up during the process.

It's important to note that in Pyrogram, a new message triggers the execution of a function in a threaded manner. Essentially, I need a way to stop the execution of one function through another function.

Could you please provide guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this functionality within Pyrogram?

Here is an example:

```py
from pyrogram import Client, filters

api_id = xxxx
api_hash = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
bot_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
app = Client("my_bot",api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash,bot_token=bot_token)

@app.on_message(filters.regex("do"))
def do(client, message):
    pass
    # A long process that takes 10 minutes.

@app.on_message(filters.regex("exit"))
def exit_func(client, message):
    pass
    
app.run()
```